# How to fill missing values in array with next non-missing value using CUDA Thrust?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

By using CUDA Thrust's [inclusive scan](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html#ga7109170b96a48fab736e52b75f423464) with a `max` operator, I'm able to fill missing values with the previous non-missing value (i.e. last non-missing value to the left).

But how to fill using next non-missing value (to the right)? Thus, for example, using `0` as my missing value marker:

```
                  Input: [0 1 0 0 4 0 6 0]
 Fill missing from left: [0 1 1 1 4 4 6 6]
Fill missing from right: [0 1 4 4 4 6 6 6]   <- want
```

*(Note if the last element is missing then revert to filling final `0`s from left.)*

I've tried a inclusive scan in reverse, which yields `[0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]` for `max`, not as desired.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you reverse the array?

Comment: Sure, @ks6g10, but I don't see how reversing the array helps solve the problem as described. Doing an inclusive scan in reverse gives `[0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6]` for `max` and `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` for `min` as operator, not `[0 1 4 4 4 6 6 6]` as desired. Please could you clarify your solution? Many thanks.

Comment: What does "forward-looking" actually mean? (I don't know how to read your O / Relation syntax thingy).

Comment: @RogerDahl, apologies for the confusion. I'm simply trying to fill the 0s in `[0 1 0 0 4 0 6 0]` with the number that comes after (to the right of) it, or if it is the rightmost element of the array, then fill using the element before (to the left of) it. Many thanks.

Comment: @MiloChen: Thanks. What had me confused was that the operator changed between the forwards- and backwards-looking examples. I thought the options were just possibilities, not applied, since the `Relation` column contained `O`, not the specific operator.

Comment: Yes, apologies @RogerDahl - I should have been clearer. The question has now been amended, so I'd be most grateful if you could have another crack at it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to handle input where the values are not always ascending? For instance, `[0 1 4 6 3 0 1 0]`.

Comment: I think you would need to 1. scan input in reverse and 2. detect where these runs begin (i.e., look for the discontinuities in the input). It seems like you should be able to do this with just a scan and a custom functor. Seems like simply using a min or max functor won't solve the problem.

Comment: @RogerDahl, as far as I can imagine my values will always be ascending. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using max , you may want to try the functor I showed to you in your last question with the reverse iterators rbegin rend

Comment: Also by the same logic, why isnt the first element 1 ?

Comment: @Pavan, because the array in question lists positions of another array I want to partition. Motivation: suppose `X = [A A B C C]` and I want to partition this array by its values - that is, I want `Y = [A_Start, B_Start, C_Start] = [0 2 3]`. With this, I can calculate how many `A`s there are by `B_Start - A_Start` Now consider what if there are no `B`s in `X`, say `X = [A A C C C]`? Now `Y = [0, ?, 2]` - what is `B_Start`? I still want to be able to do `A_Count = B_Start - A_Start` so I need to fill from the right and so I need `B_Start := C_Start`.

Comment: @MiloChen I think this is related to another question of yours I answered. I updated it based on your request. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `max()` works on ascending values when scanning from left to right is that the current maximum value will always be higher than your `0` missing element, so it becomes the correct value for filling in the missing elements even though it has a "memory" coming all the way from the beginning.

If you simply scan from right to left, `max()` no longer works, because you then have a descending range.

So, it seems like you need to use `rbegin()` and `rend()` to scan from right to left and, in addition, use MAX_INT as your place-holder and `min()` as your operator.

```
Input: [MAX_INT 1 MAX_INT MAX_INT 4 MAX_INT 6 MAX_INT]
Fill missing from right: [1 1 4 4 4 6 6 MAX_INT]
```

Then, you need to fudge things for your special cases on the left and right.

Comment: This works, but can you change to `thrust::minimum()` instead of `min` just to be clear. And also mention that you are using *inclusive* scan.

Answer (score 3):

The functor `FillMissing` means if element is 0, replace it with the previous element, otherwise keep it. When using reverse iterators, "previous" means the right one.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
struct FillMissing
{
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& res, const T& dat)
    {
        return dat == T(0) ? res : dat;
    }
};

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<double> vec(8);
    vec[1] = 1;
    vec[4] = 4;
    vec[6] = 6;

    thrust::inclusive_scan(
            vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(),
            vec.rbegin(),
            FillMissing<double>());

    thrust::copy(
            vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output.

```
1 1 4 4 4 6 6 0
```

You may need extra code to deal with the trailing 0s

Comment: I tested the code with the data Milo provided. It works if there is only one trailing zero.

Comment: Let me clarify, it fails if there is more than one zero at the end.

Comment: @Pavan I think the result for his data will be `11444660`

Comment: Yes you are right. I was testing it in a wrong manner. Anyway, can you edit your answer and say that special code is needed for trailing zeros ?